# appending an svg within a svg js

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to append an svg element within an svg element however the inner svg won't show.

```
.outer {
background: tomato;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
}

.inner {
background: blue;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}



let div = document.querySelector(`div`);

let svgOuter = document.createElementNS(`http://www.w3.org/2000/svg`, `svg`);
svgOuter.classList.add(`outer`);

let svgInner = document.createElementNS(`http://www.w3.org/2000/svg`, `svg`);
svgInner.classList.add(`inner`);


div.appendChild(svgOuter);
svgOuter.appendChild(svgInner);
```

http://codepen.io/BradLee/pen/beGQgv

Comment: Ahh but it does show, inner svg elements don't support the background CSS property though.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve excactly? A rectangle inside a rectangle? In that case: have a look at the group-element `<g> </g>` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g

Comment: The end goal is to draw a graph. If I use 1 svg (and have a viewBox="0 0 100 100") and then draw the x-axis at (0,0) to (0, 100), the line will be on the edge and the a-axis labels will be off the edge. So I'm using the outer svg as padding for the inner svg. Ignoring the background css property, the inner svg is at a height and width of 0x0.

Comment: I think you still should checkout the group-element. Checkout this (Lin Charts): https://css-tricks.com/how-to-make-charts-with-svg/#article-header-id-5 ... Probably more than you ask for, but you get the understanding of it :)

Comment: Inner `<svg>` elements need height and width attributes, not CSS properties.